# Populate SQL Server from csv issues

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-data-tools

I am creating a website using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I am now at the point where I need to create a database. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and created a new database project. The database is a SQL Server 2016 platform. I am trying to take data from a `.csv` file and put it into the database, but I get some errors in my SQL file.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [BirthDate] SMALLDATETIME NULL
)
GO

BULK INSERT TestTable
FROM 'C:\Users\ajs2987\Documents\projects\TestData.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

-- Check the content of the table
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
```

The error I'm getting is on the `BULK` and `SELECT` statements:

> SQL700001: This statement is not recognized in this context.

I've also attached an image of the error on my screen:

[DBERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BLMu.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, let me know if I can supply any more details.

Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: see [this](https://arcanecode.com/2013/03/28/ssdt-error-sql70001-this-statement-is-not-recognized-in-this-context/)

Comment: Hey @MethodMan, thanks for the speedy response. I also followed this tutorial, but unfortunately I was still met with the same error.

Comment: what happens when you change the file ext to .txt does it still error also make sure the DBA has enabled BULK INSERTS check that option as well

Comment: @Rakitić DAH I tried that at first and it threw another error saying the build action I selected was wrong, but this time it seemed to work -_- Anyways, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @MethodMan I actually just created the db myself so would not need to go to a DBA to enable BULK INSERTS, I could possibly do it myself. Do you know how I would do that through Visual Studio?

Comment: can you actually show a one line example of what the data looks like perhaps you could try replacing the `,` delimiter with something other than `,` also I am wondering if you have commas wrapped with in Double quotes etc.. can you show a one liner of the file contents. here are some other options - https://host4asp.net/import-csv-file-using-sql-server-management-studio/

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file

Comment: @MethodMan I instead changed the query to be a post script instead of a database definition script, and it seems to be working fine now. I still did exactly what you recommended as far as the link goes, but just changed the script to be a post script instead. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the script below, as an example, and it worked fine for me.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STAGING]
 (
        [Date]    VARCHAR(MAX),
        Type    VARCHAR(MAX),
        Change  VARCHAR(MAX),
        SP_ID   VARCHAR(MAX),
        Sedol   VARCHAR(MAX),
        Cusip   VARCHAR(MAX)
)
  bulk insert dbo.STAGING
  from 'C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\YOUR_DATA.txt'
  WITH
  (
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  )
  GO
  INSERT INTO dbo.FINAL
    SELECT
        [Date] = CASE WHEN ISDATE([Date])=1 THEN CAST([Date] AS DATETIME) ELSE NULL END,
        Type,
        Change,
        SP_ID,
        Sedol,
        Cusip
    FROM [dbo].[STAGING]
```

Make sure your file is comma-delimited...I assume it is.  Also, make sure there is no special character at the beginning of the file or at the end of the file.  Look in Notepad++ just to make sure.  Sometimes you can't see those special characters when you just look at the CSV.  :)

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing database definitions with data modification statments, which is a big no-no. You need to move your BULK INSERT and SELECT statements to a separate file that isn't "built" with your database.

Then you can reference said file as a post-deployment script (or just manually run it).

See "Pre- and Post-Deployment Scripts" in https://www.infoq.com/articles/SSDT-Intro for an example.